# What do the notifications say?

Tags: fallout-shelter

Either due to the notifications being too long, or android not scrolling the notifications, but I can't see what most of the notifications say.

The main reason for this question is

```
One of your dwellers has been...
```

but I'd also like to know all of the notifications that can appear.

Comment: ... eaten by a grue?

Comment: To read them, I usually open some other app (like a browser) that allows for the display to flip. In landscape view I can usually read them (and once read, you recognize most of them)

Comment: I'm getting them through the PushBullet for Chrome notification forwarding stuff. Was also very curious about what the "One of your dwellers has been o..." notifica(snip) for a while. Guess I have a screen one character wider than @Rapitor's.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All are prefixed by "Vault (x): "

- One of your Dwellers has been out in the Wasteland for a while, you should check on them.
- A baby is about to be born in your Vault!
- One of your babies has grown into a healthy Dweller!
- Something happened in your vault!
- One of your production rooms is ready for collecting!
- One of your Dwellers has been out in the Wasteland for a short while. Perhaps you should check on them.

Comment: I'll try and write others down, as I see them, and edit them into the Answer.

Comment: `A room as produced resources` (or pretty close to that). `A baby is about to be born`, another for a returned wanderer, one for baby growing up to adult... there's a bit too many.

Comment: I've been getting "Something happened in your vault!" So helpful.

Answer (score -2):

Here are all the cached notifications for Fallout Shelter:

[image: List of notifications cached from Fallout Shelter]

Comment: I bet vault 69 and 101 are the most popular vault numbers for FS. :)